# JavaScript in my wordpress page

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Following is my Js code which I have been trying to use in my wordpress page but its not working. Kindly let me know how to write it inside my wordpress page. The main idea of the folllowing function is to unload the Vimeo video which opens up in a modal of plugin `easy modal` when user click on close

```
<script src="http://a.vimeocdn.com/js/froogaloop2.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var iframe = $('.vimeo-player')[0];
var player = $f(iframe);

$('.close-modal').click(function() {
    alert('stoped');
    player.api('unload');
});
</script>
```

You can clearly see the code works fine in this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/8CV2S/161/

Iframe Code:

```
<iframe class="vimeo-player" src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/76079" width="1000px" height="500px" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
```

Comment: Define "it's not working."  In what way is it not working?  Is there an error on the browser's development console?  Does the code run at all?  Do the `.vimeo-player` and `.close_modal` elements exist on the page *before* this code executes?

Comment: @david yes .vimeo-player and .close_modal exists. thi line of code wa working fine before but after adding the line mentioned above the js in wordpres page is not working `jQuery("#first").click(function(){window.scrollTo(0, jQuery("#dummy").offset().top);});
`

Comment: They may exist, but where do they exist in relation to this code?  JavaScript is executed as it's loaded, so if the elements are after this code then they don't exist when this code executes.  We can't know that, because you haven't shown it to us, but it's a very common error.

Comment: @user3027531 The issue may not be limited to the markup that you have posted.  Could you post the full markup of the page on which you are trying to get this script to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this code is in the `head` of the page, then the problem is that the elements you're referencing *don't exist* when the code executes:

```
$('.vimeo-player')
$('.close-modal')
```

Since jQuery finds no matches, it doesn't do anything with them.  In order to wait for the DOM to finish loading, simply wrap the code in a jQuery function:

```
$(function () {
    var iframe = $('.vimeo-player')[0];
    var player = $f(iframe);

    $('.close-modal').click(function() {
        alert('stoped');
        player.api('unload');
    });
});
```

Additionally, you *might* have a typo here:

```
var player = $f(iframe);
```

Unless this is part of the API you're using?  (A commenter says it is.)  If this is throwing an error on your browser console, something along the lines of `$f` being undefined, maybe you meant this?:

```
var player = $(iframe);
```

That's just a guess, though.  I don't know the Vimeo API.

Comment: for some reason this header file is creating issue `<script src="http://a.vimeocdn.com/js/froogaloop2.min.js"></script>` I am confued why it happening

Comment: @David $f is actually part of the vimeo api

Comment: now i am getting this error `TypeError: $ is not a function
 

$(function () {`

Comment: @user3027531: Did you load the jQuery library?  You're using what looks like jQuery, in order to do that you'll need to add a reference to it just as you do for the Vimeo API.

Comment: surprisingly for some reason you have to tag the javascript something like this `<script type="text/javascript"><!--//--><![CDATA[//><!-- DONT GIVE ENTER SPACES  //--><!]]></script>`  now the code works fine

Comment: now just one issue is left: there are multiple modals which (iframe) contains `.vimeo-player` and the code only works for the first modal `$('.vimeo-player')[0]` is there a way to make it work for all the iframes which have `class=vimeo-player`

Comment: @user3027531: Sure.  Currently you're only running this code for the first matched element (the `[0]` array index).  You can wrap the whole thing in a call to `.each()`, where `this` would replace `iframe`.  Something like: `$('.vimeo-player').each(function () { var iframe = $(this); // the rest of the code });`

Comment: i did `$('.vimeo-player').each(function () { var iframe = $(this); var player = $f(iframe); player.api('unload');});` but it gave me error `TypeError: this.element.getAttribute is not a function` `.vimeo-player` is the class used on all the iframes

Comment: @user3027531: Why did you take out the `click` handler assignment?  The code shouldn't otherwise change, it's just being wrapped in a call to `.each()` on an array of matched elements.

Comment: no no I didnot take out that my complete code is `$('.close-modal').click(function() {
   $('.vimeo-player').each(function () { var iframe = $(this); var player = $f(iframe); player.api('unload');});
alert('hi yo');
    });` and alert is not poping up and gave the error I mentioned above

Comment: @user3027531: This seems to be an unrelated issue then.  It's not clear from how you're structuring this what you want it to do, currently you're looping in the click handler when previously it sounded like you wanted to create the click handler in a loop.  The error you're mentioning isn't in the code presented, so it could be some other misuse of the Vimeo API with which I'm not familiar.

Comment: Please David Take a look at this fiddle i made for you : http://jsfiddle.net/8CV2S/162/

Comment: @user3027531: Interesting.  I don't know why, but `this` isn't working inside that `.each()` the way I'd expect it to.  I tried inspecting it, and it is in fact an HTML iframe element object.  But it's failing in some other capacity.  I've replaced the call to `.each()` with a normal `for` loop, and it seems to do the trick: http://jsfiddle.net/8CV2S/163/

Comment: PERFECT DAVID thanks so much for your quick responses :)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding it in `document.ready`:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  var iframe = $('.vimeo-player')[0];
  var player = $f(iframe);

  $('.close-modal').click(function() {
    alert('stoped');
    player.api('unload');
  });

});
```

See http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Check if you have any syntax errors.